Using limits to prove I have an extrema
I have an exam coming up and this was one of the exercises from last year:

After finding the minimum, the limit of
$r\,V(r)$ is taken as $r \to 0$ and the limit of $V(r)$ is taken as $r \to \infty$.
My teacher has told me to draw a graph of this if I find it easier but drawing graphs are a bit harder for me.
I am wondering why this limits are taken and why is $r$ being multiplied by $V(r)$.

Any guidance would me much appreciated.

Is there also any resources I could use to study more on this stuff, I can't find anything in my textbook or youtube.
$$
V(r) = \frac{a}{r^2} - \frac{b}{r}
$$
We are asked to find the $2$nd degree taylor expansion at the point where $V$ attains its minimum.




What is $V(r)$ ? Your question is lacking some information

Yes sorry, I could not upload the problem. V(r) is the potential of two bodies = a/r^2 -b/r. We are asked to find the taylor expansion to the 2nd degree around the point where V attains it's minimum.

This is from $\tt Mathematica$ but you can do it by hand !!!.

